# OnCommand vs OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, onclick

I was doing some research on my project (ASP.NET Web Forms) and came across 2 event types that seem similar, OnCommand and OnClick. I have read through the MSDN pages but I am still unclear on the differences between them.

What is the difference between OnCommand vs OnClick and when would I want to use which event?

//edited to specify for type of app

Comment: what type of application is this? and you are performing the action on  what type of control?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: have you tried using a search engine? i quickly found this site: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?490339-onCommand-vs-onClick-for-Buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you find the documentation a bit unclear, that's understandable.

What happens is that `OnClick` is a lower-level event than `OnCommand`.  You can think of `OnClick` as being more like a physical event, and `OnCommand` as being more like a logical event, so to speak.

When the control is clicked, it receives an `OnClick` event which tells the control that there has been a click.  The control may do various things as a response.  If the control is associated with a command, and if default processing of the event is allowed to take place, then the system will follow this with an `OnCommand` event.

<sup>(I am not sure / don't remember how much control you have over the suppression of default processing in WinForms, but you can certainly control that in the underlying Win32 programming layer.)</sup>

The `OnCommand` event may be triggered by means other than a click.  For example, you may use a keyboard shortcut to activate a control, in which case there will be no `OnClick`.

The knowledge to take home from all this is the following:

> **Never use OnClick when OnCommand will suffice.**

If you write your program to use `OnClick` for triggering *Business Logic* operations, then your program will require the user to use the mouse.  There are many users who cannot use the mouse due to disability, there are many users who simply prefer the keyboard over the mouse, and there are many devices that do not even have a mouse.

<sup>(On those devices a click will often be simulated by a touch, but that's not guaranteed, and in any case all these clunky simulations should have never been necessary in the first place, the only reason they are added is because programmers were careless in the first place and they were doing silly things like triggering actions on `OnClick` instead of `OnCommand`.)</sup>

It would be okay to use `OnClick` if you were writing your own control.  For example, if you were writing your own edit box control, and you wanted the user to be able to click somewhere within the control in order to place the caret at that exact location, then it would be okay to do that as a response to the `OnClick` event being triggered.  But note how this action is for internal use of the control only, it does not trigger any action which is external to the control.

Answer (score 3):

This is straight from the msdn page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx

But trying to explain with little verbosity:

`OnCommand` is used to pass extra arguments to the handler. For example, if you have two buttons to sort list ascending and descending. Instead of writing separate `OnClick` handlers for each button , you can define single handler for both buttons and pass `CommandName` and `CommandArgument`

```
    <asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Sort Ascending"
       CommandName="Sort"
       CommandArgument="Ascending"
       OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
       runat="server"/>

    <asp:Button id="Button2"
       Text="Sort Descending"
       CommandName="Sort"
       CommandArgument="Descending"
       OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
       runat="server"/>


    void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
    {

       switch(e.CommandName)
       {

         case "Sort":

           // Call the method to sort the list.
           Sort_List((String)e.CommandArgument);
           break;
       }

   }
```

so here you have single handler where you can handle multiple buttons' clicks depending on what command argument buttons are passing.

Answer (score 0):

Within the MSDN documentation it states in the remarks section the key difference.

With OnCommand:

`The Command event is raised when the Button control is clicked. This event is commonly used when a command name, such as Sort, is associated with the Button control. This allows you to create multiple Button controls on a Web page and programmatically determine which Button control is clicked.`

With OnClick:

`The Click event is raised when the Button control is clicked. This event is commonly used when no command name is associated with the Button control (for instance, with a Submit button).`

So, if you just want some code to execute when a button is clicked, but don't care about specific execution for specific cases then `OnClick` is just fine.

Edited to add: With OnCommand you could potentially have one handler that handles events from multiple buttons and executes the proper code based on the command name that's passed.